# Opening Smart Contracts on Quorum via json rpc api eth_sendtransaction for Integration Purposes

Tags: json-rpc, quorum

if I wish to integrate quorum blockchain with other platforms via the json rpc api eth_sendtransaction method, what other implications can there be? Assuming the smart contract built is secured and that it performs the necessary checks (require, assert, etc)